# How to search on multiple fields with boost weights?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

At the moment I'm using this:

```
 response = await ElasticClient.SearchAsync<Product>(s => s
                       .From(skip)
                       .Size(productSearch.ItemsPerPage)
                       .Index(productSearch.Company + PartOfIndexName + productSearch.Country)
                       .Query(q => q
                             .QueryString(c => c
                                 .Fields(f => f
                                 .Field(p => p.IdPart1, 4.0)
                                 .Field(p => p.Title, 4.0)
                                 .Field(p => p.BrandName, 3.0)
                                 .Field(p => p.Description, 2.0)
                                 )
                                 .Query("*" + productSearch.Query + "*")
                                )
                              )
                        );
```

But this doesn't work. No results get returned. But I get a valid response (debug information: "Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST"). Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? It's been days now and I still can't figure it out.

When I query it via the Elasticsearch REST API like this:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/company_products_country/_search
```

body:

```
{
   "size": 10,
   "query": { 
    "match": { 
        "title": "something" 
    } 
   }
}
```

Then it works and I get results. But if I search the description field for something like: "787920/1", then I get no results. The description field is a 500 char text field.

I index the documents like this:

```
ElasticClient.Index(product, idx => idx.Index(indexName));
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? What version of NEST are you using and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting? What does the debug information show: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html

Comment: The NEST version which I'm using is 6.0.2 and the Elasticsearch version is 6.2.3. It doesn't return any results (this is what I meant with "doesn't work"). I get a VALID response.

Comment: @RussCam I have expanded my question a bit. Hope it helps.

Comment: @RussCam I think that I don't use the correct "type/choose the right analyzer" when I index my documents. I might be wrong about this as well... What would be the correct way to index a 500 char text if I want to query it for something like: "787920/1"?

Comment: OK, so it does work but it doesn't return the results you expect. First thing that I can see is the use of wildcards in the query. For these to work, you need to set `.AnalyzeWildcard()` inside `.QueryString(...)`. You may still not get the results you're looking for though, as the input may not be analyzed in a way to fit your search use case. Here, you may need to specify a different analyzer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-analyzers.html

Comment: @RussCam could you suggest which analyzer would be the most appropriate for in this case?

Comment: it's tricky to make general suggestions without knowing sufficient detail about your project. To get you started in the right direction, if you need to search for terms like `787920/1`, you likely want an analyzer that analyzes and indexes terms in that way, perhaps using a pattern tokenizer or pattern capture token filter.